# Why the Euler characteristics of a compact connected lagrangian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Let's consider space $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the standard symplectic structure and let $L\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ be a compact connected embedded submanifold. There is a fact that if $L$ is lagrangian submanifold, then it is a torus, or, equivalently in this case, $\chi(L)=0$. I saw this fact in many books and articles, but all proofs I could find are either not very detailed or too difficult for me. More precisely, I am interested in these facts: why, if $L$ is otientable, then $\chi(L)=0$; why, if $L$ is not orientable, then $\chi(L)\equiv 0 (\text{mod 2})$. Both facts as I understood are easy, but in all proofs I saw there are some moments I do not understand.
I will give some information about my knowledge and problems that I have reading proofs of this fact.
I know about Weinstein's neighborhood theorem. I understood that I have to use that some neighborhood of $L$ is symplectomorphic to some neighborhood of zero-section in cotangent bundle $T^* L$. Also, many proofs use isomorphism $TL≅T^* L≅NL$. I understand that these isomorphisms exist but do not know why it is useful here. Then, I know about Euler characteristics as a number of zeros (with signes or modulo two) of a generic vector field on a manifold. Also, I am a bit familiar with the intersection index of two submanifolds, so as I understand Euler characteristics of submanifold is the intersection index of the zero-section in its tangent bundle with itself.
It seems to me that I have all instruments to proof these facts but concrete steps I do not see. Could you help me please?

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4128674/11127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the homological intersection number of L with a pushoff. If the pushoff is using a section of the normal bundle (which is isomorphic to the tangent bundle) then you get minus the Euler characteristic because that's the homological intersection of a section of the tangent bundle with the zero section. However, you can also pushoff using a translation in $\mathbb{C}^n$, which displaces L from itself if you translate far enough because L is compact and hence bounded. This gives intersection number zero. Now notice that if L is orientable then homological intersection number can be computed using any pushoff by standard results in differential topology (it's just $[L]^2$). If it's not orientable then this still works mod 2. In fact, as observed by Audin, using the Pontryagin square instead of $[L]^2$, you get the result modulo 4 in the non-orientable setting. In fact, you don't need the Weinstein neighbourhood theorem, only the fact that normal and tangent bundles are isomorphic (which is strictly easier: it just uses linear algebra rather than Moser's argument).

The same strategy tells you the Euler characteristic equals $[L]^2$ in general (not just in $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Comment: Could you, please, explain the step with pushing off using section of normal bundle more precisely? I will start as I understand it. Locally in charts for every point of L we can find two independent vector fields with compact support that are normal to tangent space of L. Because of compactness of L we can find finitely many of those charts that cover L. For every field from this finite set we create a flow. We compose an inclusion map of L with all of these flows. This new map is transversal to L. So, by Thom's theorem almost every "deformation" of inclusion map is transversal to L.

Comment: Then, I do not exactly understand how to connect our new map (say it F) with what I need. Okey, F is homotopic to inclusion map and transversal to L, so self-intersection number of L is equal to I(F, L). But how this index is connected with intersection number of some section of normal bundle and zero-section?

Comment: The self-intersection number of L is a number which depends only on the class of L in homology. It can be calculated by counting (with signs) intersections of L with F(L) where F is any diffeomorphism isotopic to the identity making L and F(L) transverse. In particular, the 'large translation' is isotopic to the identity and disjoins L from F(L) (definitely transverse).

Comment: The 'small pushoff in the normal bundle' could be defined as follows. Pick a section of the normal bundle which vanishes transversely. Choose a vector field on the total space of the normal bundle defined as follows. On every fibre of the normal bundle, V is tangent to the fibre and everywhere parallel to the vector pointing from 0 to the value of the section. Now multiply this with a bump function supported near the zero section. The flow of L along this vector field gives the pushoff of L and it can be imported into C^n by the tubular neighbourhood theorem.